# AWS auth ui sdk requires minSdkVersion 23, why?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-sdk

I am setting up my android app with AWS backend and am compiling the `com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.+@aar` library requires minSdkVersion to be 23 in the app level gradle file, however I wish to use 19 as the minSdkVersion. Here is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jwb.juicewithbenefits"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // Mobile Client for initializing the SDK
    compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar') { transitive = true; }
    // Cognito UserPools for SignIn
    compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }
    // Sign in UI Library
    compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true; }
}
```

Here is the error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.6.13] /Users/tomfinet/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aws-android-sdk-auth-ui-2.6.13.aar/7dfb53c482a0be1de8d21de2413312fd/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

When I use 23 as the `minSdkVersion` the gradle build completes successfully but not with 19. How can I use `minSdkVersion` 19 and build gradle successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui` was introduced in v2.6.0 [Commit reference](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/commit/b1fd18d23ea0ea30bf54a8396fccbbae2430f792#diff-506ba80ff4e9f5dcf4e4a69c9e4dfa0f).

In that commit, the v23 platform dependencies got introduced ([aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/pom.xml](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/b1fd18d23ea0ea30bf54a8396fccbbae2430f792/aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/pom.xml)):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>23.0.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
  <version>23.0.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>cardview-v7</artifactId>
  <version>23.0.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

So you need v23 Android SDK to be able to use `aws-android-sdk-auth`.

Comment: Means to use aws mobile hub with android we must need minimum sdk 23 ?

Comment: @DevganiyaHitesh, yeah, as it is shown from POM file

Comment: Any other recommendation to use amazon cognito service below API 23 ?

Comment: @DevganiyaHitesh, Reported here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/471. Please help me by voting it.

Comment: @chenrui, this just says that it is dependent on v23 of com.android.support (which has a minSdkVersion of 14).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html) for `aws-android-sdk-auth-ui` states that the library depends on the Android SDK API Level 23 or higher.  In another answer here, it is trying to prove this by looking at the `com.android.support` dependencies.  These are version 23.0.0, but they have their own `minSdkVersion` on the Android SDK (which is a separate matter).  The Android Support Libraries didn't require `API 14` until v26.0.

Looking at [aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/build.gradle](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/build.gradle), you can se that `minSdkVersion` is set to 23.

From [Getting Started using the SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android#getting-started-using-the-sdk) on the github repo:

> Please note the AWS SDK for Android supports Android API level 10+ and
>   newer libraries may require higher API level 21+ and 23+.